# css hide button until div hover

Tags: css, hide

We want to hide button until we hover over the div layer.

FIDDLE here > **[Click to view](http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/dTLaF/)**

Essentially, I would like to be able to apply this to other elements also, but this will do for now, any help appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
.resultContainer:hover .viewThisResult { display: block; }
```

`:hover` pseudoselector on the parent. Though it's nice when the code for the question is included in the question, for posterity.

Comment: thanks, you forgot: .viewThisResult {display:none} but cheers , works a charm

Comment: Right, sorry. Had it in the fiddle, which I failed at linking too and gave up on too quickly. :)

Comment: Note that this will make your button inaccessible to keyboard-only users. You should also display the element on `:focus` or `:focus-within`.

Answer (score 18):

Simply use the `:hover` pseudo-class on the outer div:

```
.resultContainer .viewThisResult {
    display: none;
}
.resultContainer:hover .viewThisResult {
    display: inline;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dTLaF/1/

Answer (score 0):

when using this feature and trying to hover most of the time it doesn't work because when something is hidden it is no longer there to activate hover, the simplest way to solve this is by making it transparent and using hover to remove the transparency.